# How to maximize composability with React higher-order functions?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, composition, higher-order-components

I refer to [this part of the official React tutorial (Convention: Maximizing Composability)](https://reactjs.org/docs/higher-order-components.html#convention-maximizing-composability):

```
// connect is a function that returns another function
const enhance = connect(commentListSelector, commentListActions);
// The returned function is a HOC, which returns a component that is connected
// to the Redux store
const ConnectedComment = enhance(CommentList);
```

How should we implement the connect() function?

Comment: You can check the realization of connect here: https://blog.jakoblind.no/learn-react-redux-by-coding-the-connect-function-yourself/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Conceptually HOC connect is something like this:

```
function connect(mapStateToProps, mapDispatchToProps) {
  return function (WrappedComponent) {
    return class extends React.Component {
      render() {
        return (
          <WrappedComponent
            {...this.props}
          />
        )
      }
    }
  }
}
```

How you can see, it's a function that return another function.

At first call connect get 2 arguments

```
const enhance = connect(commentListSelector, commentListActions);
```

At the second it get Component which we return in connect function

```
const ConnectedComment = enhance(CommentList);
```

But not only component, we return connect with new props which we get from redux - so it's approach how to get data from redux, look at more detailed example (if it's not enough for you, you can check link in a comment above):

```
function connect(mapStateToProps, mapDispatchToProps) {
  return function (WrappedComponent) {
    return class extends React.Component {
      render() {
        return (
          <WrappedComponent
            {...this.props}
            {...mapStateToProps(store.getState(), this.props)}
            {...mapDispatchToProps(store.dispatch, this.props)}
          />
        )
      }
    } 
  } 
}
```

For me more useful and convenient is react-hook pattern, check useSelector and useDispatch methods to get data from redux component to react. It's simplier, connect a legacy approach and can be useful only with Class components.